# Reading a UTF-16 file into core data

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, utf-16

I have a csv file that is utf-16 containing Tamil characters and displays fine as I view it.  I read it into my iphone/ipad program and creates a core data database from it.  The problem I have is that the information gets stored in the core database in another character set.  How do I specify to use UTF16StringEncoding while I build the database from the csv?  Here is my loading method:

```
- (void)setupQuestions {
NSString *paths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *bundlePath = [paths stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"questions_tm.csv"];
NSString *dataFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:bundlePath];
NSArray *dataRows = [dataFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
[dataFile release];

//Question *card;
for (int i = 0 ; i < [dataRows count] ; i++)
{
    NSArray *dataElements = [[dataRows objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    if ([dataElements count] >= 1)
    {
        card = (Question *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Question" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
        NSLog(@"Row ID: %i", i);
        card.ID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
        card.answer = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[dataElements objectAtIndex:1] intValue]];
        card.question = [dataElements objectAtIndex:2];
        card.optionA = [dataElements objectAtIndex:3];
        card.optionB = [dataElements objectAtIndex:4];
        card.optionC = [dataElements objectAtIndex:5];
        card.optionD = [dataElements objectAtIndex:6];


        [self save];
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `card.question` is the `NSString` you want in `UTF16StringEncoding`, you have at least the following two options:

```
NSString* question = [dataElements objectAtIndex:2];
const char * questionCString = [question cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
card.question = [[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:questionCString encoding:UTF16StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Option 2:

```
NSString* question = [dataElements objectAtIndex:2];
NSData* questionData = [question dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
card.question = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:questionData encoding:UTF16StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Comment: I tried using option 2.  Note:  add "NS" in front of UTF16StringEncoding.  It compiles and makes sense to me, but does not work.  I went into a sqlite browser and noticed that the encoding is UTF-8 for the dbase.  How would I change how this gets encoded by Xcode?  If the dbase does not exist, I create it in the program.

Comment: I also suspect that somehow I am not telling the project what encoding to use.  I went into Xcode preferences and changed it from UTF-8 to UTF-16, but I am not sure that is all that is needed to be done for an existing project to have it's character set encoding changed.

Comment: Thanks for the 'NS'. Edited my answer. What do you mean by "encoding is UTF-8 for the db"? One question, is it not possible for you to store the data is UTF-8 & convert it back to UTF-16 when you fetch it from the DB?

Comment: I don't think Xcode's preferences has anything to do with the encoding of the DB that you create. I would be really surprised if it changes anything.

Comment: After running debug, I noticed that as I load the elements from the CSV file it is reading them in with the wrong encoding.  Here is the line that reads the CSV that shows the data in the wrong format:  NSArray *dataRows = [dataFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];                                  How would I go about encoding this for UTF-16?

Comment: I think in the line where you create dataFile, you should be using initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:. Specifying NSUTF16StringEncoding would return the result  in UTF-16. HTH!

Comment: Thank you for your help Akshay!  I also found the same information as your last comment.

Comment: NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"act texts" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *sourceData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:sourcePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];